# create a button next to the new button odoo 16

Tags: xml, button, view, action, odoo-16

does anyone know how to create a button beside new button, i got confused and dont know how to implement this, so in my custome module i want to make a button next to the new button that can go to my transient model but i dont know how to put in there [image: the example]

```
<record id="view_hospital_patient_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">hospital.patient.tree</field>
            <field name="model">hospital.patient</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree>
                    <header>
                        <button name="action_open_patient_report" string="Report" type="object" invisible="0"/>
                    </header>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="age"/>
                    <field name="gender"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

i already tried like this but it only shows when i clicked the list on the tree view

i want to make another button in my custom module next to the new button like that